# How to fix Module Not Found Error: No module named 'keras'when the module absolutly has been installed

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to install some machine learning libraries on a new Windows laptop (I usually have Mac laptops in case that matters). I set up a virutal environment with python 3.6.8 (since that is highest version for tensorflow/keras). Installed the keras library and everyhting went well.

Now, in a terminal, I activated my virtual environment `conda activate mlenv` then checked the libaries installed via `conda list` and Keras 2.2.4 is there.

Next in a terminal I run `import keras' and get the "Using TensorFlow backend" output, confirming it is installed correctly.

But in that same environment, when I run a python file from Code Studio, which imports keras, I get a No module named 'keras' error. I have uninstalled and re-installed and still have the same issue.

Comment: All I can think of is that you aren't really in the same environment when you run your python file from Code Studio.  If I understand correctly what you've said, there has to be something different between the environment Code Studio is attempting to run the script in vs when running it at the command line in your virtualenv.  Maybe this is obvious and wrong.  It's just all I can see making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve. That comment led me to the answer. So, even though the terminal showed that it was in the mlenv environment I created as: `(mlenv) Y:\MaRoss\>` when I `Run Python File in Terminal`, Code Studio's current python interpreter (i.e. environment) is called and the file is run within it rather than the `mlenv` one. Meaning the environement which didn't have Keras installed. Trying to switch interpreters by running the `Python: Select Interpreter` command in the command palette wasn't showing the virtual environments I created (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). Which apparently Windows has trouble recognizing new environments. Had to restart Code Studio, it recognized the environment, switched intepreters and all ran correctly. Thanks.